# Why are the calculated dates different in Internet Explorer and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

So I'm using this to try to get the day before today. This works fine in Chrome but IE thinks its the day before that. My current system date is 09/05/2014 10:14 (PST).

```
var todaysDate = new Date();
var maxDate = new Date(Date.UTC(todaysDate.getFullYear(),todaysDate.getMonth(),todaysDate.getDate()-1));
```

Its worth mentioning that both IE and Chrome return the value 9 for the following.

```
console.log(todaysDate.getDate());
```

So if today = 09/05/2014 (PST)

Chrome gets 08/05/2014

IE gets 07/05/2014

What's going on? Why is IE interpreting this differently to Chrome?

Comment: I get `Wed May 07 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` in Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m and IE11.

Comment: Ah I totally forgot to mention my current system time is set to PST and 10:14 09/05/2014. The reason being this seems to cause the issue, IE and Chrome do sometimes return the same values but not with this system date/time.

Comment: it works fine for me on IE as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a timezone issue - timezones behind GMT will be pushed back a day by your code.

<del>Try setting the "hours" to `12`. This will ensure that all timezones are on the same day.</del>

So apparently UTC+14 is a thing. Try `todaysDate.getUTC*` methods instead and be sure to include the hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: Some time zones have an offset higher than 12 hours, so this probably won't gracefully solve everyone's problems. [Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC.2B14:00.2C_M.E2.80.A0)

Comment: @AdmiralAdama ... Well sh- bug- erm... darn?

Comment: I am pretty confident there are countries led by cynical old developers who lost the argument that everything should always be in UTC. Now they lead a crusade of timezone offset battles causing bugs to run rampart. Think they are all whole hours? *Nope*, think they are at least every half hour in those weird cases? *Nope*, one lands on :45. And **who knows** what happens across the International Date Line.

Comment: Replaced my method with with the UTC ones. IE and Chrome are both working fine. Thanks. I have to wonder why this was only an issue in IE though...

Comment: @dlampard IE tends to be closer-tied in to the OS, particularly when it comes to locales, formats and date/times.